# showing and hiding divs with select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show content on selecting the select tag. I am using change() function to do that but it is not really picking up the right content on change. Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/NhL2V/

The html looks like this

```
<table id="formTable">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Investment cycle:</td>
                    <td>
                    <select class="selectOption">
                        <option>Jan12</option>
                        <option>Feb12</option>
                        <option>Mar12</option>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>   
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Subsequent investments will occur on:</td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="changingArea">
                            <div class="descContent">Content A</div>
                            <div class="descContent">Content B</div>
                            <div class="descContent">Content C</div>
                        </div>
                    </td>   
                </tr>
            </table>
```

The jquery looks like this

```
$(function() {

    $('.selectOption').change(function(){
        $('.descContent').hide();
        $('.descContent').eq($(this).index('.selectOption')).show();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the index of the selected option element, you can use `selectedIndex` property of DOM [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLSelectElement) object.

```
//  You can chain the methods
$('.descContent').hide().eq(this.selectedIndex).show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NhL2V/2/